# compare input strings and store in database if that is equal

Tags: java, string

I want to compare input string get from html using bean with certain strings that I will use constant in my code and if that input strings are equal with the specified string i want to store that user  as a admin in database where I have to update row in database table.thank  you

Comment: Good to know you're so willing and wishful to achieve your goals!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You forgot describe problem which is stopping you from doing what you want. To update your question use [edit] option.

Comment: I wish all the best to you....BTW whats the problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private final String User_role ="admin";

if(User_role.eguals(UserRole.getUser())){
    PreparedStatement st = session.connection().prepareStatement("{update tblUser user set user.user_role = ? where (Condition)}");
    st.setString(1,User_role );
    st.execute();
}
```